# Assign values from one column of pandas dataframe to the list of parameters in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in a csv file that contains a column of parameter names, and then several columns of values under different scenarios.  I want to assign the parameter values from a specific column to the parameters.  How can I do this?  The order of the rows will change.

In this simple example, I effectively want to have
`a = 1 b = 2 c = 3`
Note that the values will be read in from a csv

MWE

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'params':["a", "b", "c"], 'value':[1,2,3]} 
df =  pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

I am using python3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately I lost the page where I got the idea for this so cannot give proper credit, but this is what ended up working for me

```
exec("%s = %d" %(params, df.iloc[params, value]))
```

where I iterated over the params

Answer (score 0):

Create Series and then select by `params` values:

```
s = df.set_index('params')['value']
print (s)
a    1
b    2
c    3
Name: value, dtype: int64

print (s['a'])
1

print (s['b'])
2

print (s['c'])
3
```